# TAR'ing files in different directories

Tags: shell

Never coded in Shell before, need to TAR 7 files, 5 are located in one directory, two are located in another. Sounds simple, right? Should be. I'm guessing that we assign variables to each file, then TAR them up. How does this syntax work?

Answer (score 0):

```
tar -zcvf -T <file_name> abc.tar.gz
```

where `<file_name>` contains list of file to be included in .tar.gz

Comment: So i'm setting up the directories. I have DIR1 and DIR2. I want to setup an array that has all the unique filenames, these also won't change. Then i want to run a for loop that goes through each name and searched in the directories, then assign those to another array. then tar that array

Comment: You have 7 files .. Just put the path of these 7 files in a file and use that file name with -T option. You can try 'man tar ' and look for -T option there ...

Comment: this isn't working. It's saying it cannot open FILES

        FILES="/home1/t01jkxj/shell";

        tar -zcvf -T <FILES> abc.tar.gz;

Comment: cat /home1/t01jkxj/shell|xargs tar cf archive.tar

Comment: cat /home1/t01jkxj/shell|xargs tar cf archive.tar